# Adding styling to a portion of a <text> tag depending on the value it contains

Tags: css, highcharts

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uspe132s/) what I'm after is giving all the 0s in the YAxis a grey colour without affecting the numbers that are bigger than 0. The issue here is that they are contained in the same SVG tag: `<tspan>3000</tspan>`. Is there a way I can target a particular text value inside a tag using css? i.e.

```
tspan[0]{
 color: #808080;
}
```

Or is there a way I can do that using Highcharts' [yAxis.labels.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally hacky, but I got it to work. Under yaxis:

```
labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var label = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
                label = label.replace(/(0+$)/,'<span style="color: #ccc;">$1</span>');
                return label;
            }
        },
```